# Lawn cracks under fence

Tags: watering

Today, I found a long crack at the back of my lawn that runs under my wrought iron fence.  I am watering at 12:00AM for 7 minutes at each station three times a week.  I don’t want my fence to fall over so what do you fill the cracks in with?

We live 9 miles South of Denton, Texas and rain has fallen all around us but it seems to evade my yard.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you water at midnight?  How much water is produced at 7 minutes each station?  Stop watering at midnight.  Is this some city wide suggestion in Denton to conserve water?  Ugh.  Water early morning only.  Water deeply and allow to dry out before watering again. What is your weekly allotment of water in Denton?  I am hoping your fence posts are in concrete, yes???  If so do not worry about your fence falling over.  Fill the cracks in with the soil between your plant beds and your lawn.  Create a little trench between beds and lawn. What kind of grass are you growing?

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: Hi JAH! We haven't seen you around for a while. Do you still need some advice? We'd like to help, we just need some more information from you. If there's anything your having trouble with, like editing your question of posting pictures, just let us know! Thanks!